# Sharepoint AJAX - Not Displaying Images in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I'm relatively new to some of the more cross-function code within Sharepoint 2010.

I have a project where I'm pulling the images from a Picture Library with an AJAX call and appending them to a slideshow.

Everything is great with Firefox, but Chrome yields no actual pictures that are posting.

I have 0 errors in console, and I can clearly see that the pictures are being found... they just aren't appending to my slideshow.

[image: Sharepoint Network Response]

In fact, ALL of the XML code is coming back just fine:

[image: XML Data]

I suppose I'll post the relevant code and see if any of you Sharepoint Experts can find the problem?

```
$(function(){
    startSlider();
    var refreshSlider = setInterval(function(){startSlider()},10000);
});
function startSlider() {
    $('#refresher').fadeIn(500, function(){
        $('#refresher').fadeOut(500);
    });
    $('.bjqs').remove();
    $('#banner-fade').append('<ul class="bjqs"></ul>');
    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>{AD5C33CD-0A21-4A86-9E32-927B515D09DF}</listName> \
                     <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";
    $.ajax({
        url:  "//"+window.location.hostname+L_Menu_BaseUrl+"/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
};
function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        imageUrl="//"+window.location.hostname + "/" + $(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split(";#")[1];

        var liHtml = "<li>" ;
        liHtml+="<IMG border=0 alt='' src='" + imageUrl + "' >";
        liHtml+="</li>";
        
        $(".bjqs").append(liHtml);
    });

    //Start Slider
      var height = $(window).height() - 220;
      var width = $(window).width() - 220;
      $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
        height      : height,
        width       : width,
        showcontrols: false,
        showmarkers : false,
        usecaptions : false,
        responsive  : true
      });
}
```

Surely Chrome handles DOM events differently, but I can't seem for the life of me to find anything wrong here. The images aren't even appending to the DOM in Inspect Element.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just curious why are you calling ajax request after every 10 seconds. Firstly can you try removing that..and see if it is loading images for first time. Also for Images give alt attribute some value that way you will see if image tag is getting appended or not. Image loading will take time depending on the size of image. I see your images are around 500kb each! so imagine around 10 images being loaded i.e. around 5mb of data. So by the time your image loads you are initiating another ajax request!

Comment: Valid points. The content will be refreshing at a slower rate, I just have it on 10sec for testing purposes. As far as the imgs go, I'm currently on a private network with upwards of 600mb/s. That shouldn't be the issue, but I'll give the alt tags a try. **Update** literally no **li** items are even being generated, much less **img** elements.

Comment: ok which jquery version you are using, i see "$find("z\\:row")" works in firefox and chrome but ie has issue http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10377. Why don't you use Spservices and filternode function, http://spservices.codeplex.com/releases/view/68781